A vote to do away with the sarcasm
I am going out on a limb here to make a humble request to all of the seasoned StackExchange Chem veterans that you limit the sarcastic responses to new contributors. The idea here is to encourage folks to introduce new topics and ask their questions. Sometimes I see single-phrase answers that may 'answer' the question, but do it in a less than gentlemanly way. Thank you.

Note the help pages for the site summarize the behavior expected of participants (outlined in more detail in the code of conduct):

Be nice. Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share what you know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together. Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do.

Comments deemed sarcastic can be considered non-welcoming so are discouraged. They can be flagged for editing or removal. Please keep in mind however that what strikes one person as offensive sarcasm might not be to another (e.g. might be considered playful banter). Use flags if you disagree.
